# Getting error on scons on hp ux to build simple helloworld app

Tags: scons

on HP UX I have installed scons for the first time and in the same folder I have a test.c which is a simple hello world printf executable.

when I try to run scons to build test.c it is failing by giving following error

`$ scons`

> SCons import failed. Unable to find engine files in:
>         `/usr/local/bin/../engine
>         /usr/local/bin/scons-local-3.0.1
>         /usr/local/bin/scons-local
>         /usr/local/lib/scons-3.0.1
>         /usr/local/lib/scons-3.0.1
>         /usr/lib/scons-3.0.1
>         /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scons-3.0.1
>         /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scons-3.0.1
>         /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scons-3.0.1
>         /usr/local/lib/scons-3.0.1
>         /usr/local/lib/scons
>         /usr/local/lib/scons
>         /usr/lib/scons
>         /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scons
>         /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scons
>         /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scons
>         /usr/local/lib/scons
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>       "/usr/local/bin/scons", line 192, in module import SCons.Script
>       "/usr/local/lib/scons-3.0.1/SCons/Script/__init__.py", line 82, in module import SCons.Environment
>       "/usr/local/lib/scons-3.0.1/SCons/Environment.py", line 55, in module
>       import SCons.Platform
>       "/usr/local/lib/scons-3.0.1/SCons/Platform/__init__.py", line 53, in 
>       module import tempfile`

How can I get rid of these errors?

Comment: How did you install scons? What version of SCons? What version of Python?

Comment: hp-ux had a default version of Python = 2.7.1

Comment: Version of SCons I instaled was 3.0.1

Comment: I downloaded a tar.gz file of SCons and unzipped it and installed it as shown in

Comment: https://scons.org/doc/2.3.0/HTML/scons-user/x167.html

Comment: python setup.py install --version-lib

Comment: Do you need to use --version-lib ?

Comment: can i get any guideline on how to configure it

Comment: Any reason you need to use --version-lib? (That will affect what is the correct answer to your question)

Answer (score 0):

We finally got his fixed by downloading libz.so file from the net for hp ux. Thanks.